# How do you build a wheel outside of a repo containing the package?

Tags: python, pip, python-wheel

### Question

Is there a way to build a wheel for a package while in a different repository such that the wheel has been built exactly as it would be if you built the wheel inside of the repository containing the package?

### Example

Consider the following repo:

```
/repo-containing-your-package
      |___ your_module/
      |___ setup.py
```

#### Build method A

When I run `python setup.py bdist_wheel` from within `repo-containing-your-package` it builds the wheel as expected, including `your_module`. This means after I install `pip install ./dist/your_module-#.#.#-py3-none-any.whl` (which is successful), I can run `python -m your_module.foo` from the command line.

When the package is building, I get output that verifies that my module has been picked up by the wheel:

```
creating 'dist/your_module-#.#.#-py3-none-any.whl' and adding 'build/bar' to it
adding 'your_module/__init__.py'
etc...
```

#### Build method B

However, if I run `python ../repo-containing-your-package/setup.py bdist_wheel` from a repository that is a sibling to `repo-containing-your-package`, it does not build the wheel as expected, as it fails to include `your_module`. This means after I install `pip install ./dist/your_module-#.#.#-py3-none-any.whl` (which is successful), attempting `python -m your_module.foo` fails:

```
Error while finding module specification for 'your_module.foo' (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'your_module')
```

The fact that the module has not been properly installed with the package is confirmed by reviewing the build output, which does not include the `adding 'your_module'` output that method A includes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two solutions I know of:

#### change working directory in `setup.py`

If you can modify the setup script, you can change the working directory programmatically. Add an `os.chdir` call early enough in the setup script:

```
import os
from setuptools import setup

os.chdir(os.path.dirname(__file__))

setup(...)
```

You can also change the working directory with other means without having to modify the setup script, e.g. in `bash`:

```
$ pushd path/to/repo; python setup.py bdist_wheel; popd
```

#### Use `pip wheel`

`pip` has a subcommand `wheel` that builds a wheel from the given arg; this arg is usually the name of the package, but can be a directory containing the setup script. Pass `-e` in that case so the wheel has the correct name:

```
$ pip wheel -e path/to/repo
```

Comment: I only tried the second suggested method, but it worked exactly as I wanted with some slight modifications: `pip wheel -e ../repo-containing-your-package -w dist --no-deps`. Thanks!

Comment: Happy to help! :-)