# Google Cloud Functions (python) - Using a git library in requirements.txt

Tags: python, git, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I am having trouble figuring out how to use a python library from github in GCF. Typically, i can install this library using pip: "pip install git+https://github.com/willnaoosmith/monday.git", however in GCF, libraries are added using the requirments.txt file. This file does not seem to work with these git links. How can i add in this library, without having to mess with Artifact Registry, or self hosting it somewhere else.

Ive looked into artifact registry and it seemed a bit complicated for this task. Not sure if this is the only route, or there is a straight forward solution to this.

Comment: I have not verified this answer, but see if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35998253/8016720

Answer (score 0):

Seems you want to use a custom fork of the `monday` Python client rather than the official one hosted on PyPi. You have two options:

1. build a wheel from the repo, and install it locally. More information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62271595/how-do-you-build-a-wheel-outside-of-a-repo-containing-the-package) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62956690/install-local-wheel-file-with-requirements-txt).
2. fork the repo (or contact the owner to request a release version creation), create a release version with the artifact, and add it to the requirements file. More information [here](https://zameermanji.com/blog/2022/8/17/how-to-use-github-to-host-python-wheels/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63162354/pip-install-via-requirements-txt-specify-a-direct-github-private-repo-branch-n).

I haven't worked with deploying GCFs in Python (in Java though) but hope this is enough to get you started.

Comment: Thankyou, i decided to build a wheel.